# how do I find the middle index of an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, indexing

I'm new, so this will be a stupid question. I got an assignment to create a global array, in which I will need to import objects, as they're added to an input field in the html document. Then from there, I need to update the current list on the html document, but I need to add the middle element of the array to the list, and then empty the array. My question is, how do I find the middle index and add it to the array? I tried the following code

```
const ulList = document.querySelector("ul");
                        const liElement = document.createElement("li");
                        liElement.innerHTML = `${globalArray[globalArray.length / 2 - 1].key} ${globalArray[globalArray.length / 2 - 1].manufacturer} ${globalArray[globalArray.length / 2 - 1].model}`
                        ulList.appendChild(liElement);
                        globalArray.splice(globalArray[globalArray.length / 2 - 1], 1);
```

Comment: You could try getting the length of the array and dividing by two, but that doesn't guarantee a value existing at that index. See `new Array(4)[2] // undefined`

Comment: Your logic `globalArray.length/2-1` is in the right direction, but what happens if globalArray.length is an odd number (e.g. 5?)

Comment: You could always round down if the length is odd?

Comment: So what was wrong with the code in your question?

Comment: If you aren't expecting `HTML`, don't use `innerHTML`, you can use `innerText` or `textContent`. For security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getArrayMidKey(myArray) {
  let midKeyIndex = Math.floor(myArray.length / 2)
  return midKeyIndex;
}
let snacks = array("Cake", "Soda", "Apples", "Doritos");
midSnack = snacks[getArrayMidKey(snacks));
// midSnack --> "Soda"
```

This gives you the middle key of any given array..

If the array has 5 items, it will give you item number 2, if it has 6 or 7 items - it gives you item number 3 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.floor(globalArray.length / 2)


globalArray[Math.floor(globalArray.length / 2)]
```

Try this